# Easier way to extract points from data?

Tags: python, netcdf4

I am analysing the output of a weather model, using the python module netCDF4 and makeing images with mpl_toolkits Basemap.

I made some contour plots of air pressure, which was quite easy. Now I want to add barbs for the wind, and ended up with [a plot with only wind over the seas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38ADu.png). After some fiddling around, I discovered that the basemap function fillcontinents() actually overlays these wind barbs, even though the barbs function is called later. So, removing the fillcontinents() function gave [all wind barbs as wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFpdJ.png).

**Is there a way to have filled continents, but still have all my barbs in the plot?**

My code looks somewhat like this (some graphical parameters I've left out, they are not important for my question):

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np

file = 'W:/projects/wrfout_d01_2013-10-27_120000'
data = Dataset(file)

# Load grid
longrid = data.variables['XLONG'][:].squeeze() # Removes time dimension
latgrid = data.variables['XLAT'][:].squeeze()

# Load surface pressure
p_surf = data.variables['PSFC'][:].squeeze()

# Load wind components
u = data.variables['U10'][:].squeeze()
v = data.variables['V10'][:].squeeze()

m = Basemap(projection='cyl', resolution='l',
                    llcrnrlat= 42., llcrnrlon= -12.,
                    urcrnrlat= 57., urcrnrlon= 12.)
m.drawcountries()
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents('#FAF0E6') ### Blanking out this line gives barbs over land
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,180,10),labels=[0,0,1,1])
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,10),labels=[1,0,0,0])

x,y = m(longrid,latgrid)
ct = m.contour(x,y,p_surf, colors='#1C8CFC') ### So far, so good
ct.clabel(fmt='%1i')

m.barbs(x,y,u,v)

plt.savefig('p_surf-barbs-map.png')
```

Comment: Looks to me like the `fillcontinents` artist has a higher zorder than the `barbs` artist, such that although you plot the barbs after the fillcontinents, the fillcontinents artist still ends up on top. For some reason, I can't import `basemap`. Can you check whether you can pass a zorder (e.g. 100) to barbs, or whether `Basemap.barbs` returns an artist that has a `set_zorder` method (`artist = m.barbs(x,y,u,v); artist.set_zorder(100)`)?

Comment: @Paul You did put me on the right path, and the issue is fixed now, so thank you! Turns out you can just say m.barbs(x,y,u,v,zorder=100) without the need to make the barbs a separate variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Paul I found the solution:

when plotting the barbs, add a variable zorder with a high value (I used 100) like this:

```
m.barbs(x, y, u, v, zorder=100)
```